# real time detection of typed urls: common approach?

Tags: python, html, css, qt, url

In a richtext-editor, how to perform real time formatting of urls?

SOMEWHERE in the web there HAS be an example, but I can't find any.

Here is what I already can do:

- detect the links (starting with http. or www.)
- insertHtml with `<a href=http://link>link</a>`

QtextCharFormat setAnchorHref(link) seems not to work, because it creates a

```
<a href="www.bild.de">
```

that does nothing, if I manually enter

```
<a href="http://www.bild.de">
```

it works but this is the reason why I can't use setAnchorHref.

So the devil's in the detail and so here are some problems:

- How do I keep the surrounding tags like `<b>` and such? Those i have set via

  ```
      font.setBold(True)
      cur.mergeCharFormat(cur.charFormat())
  ```
- like the windows sticky notes: When you type a link and then a space, it recognizes the space and removes the blue color. In my program, it keeps the blue color style of a link.
- If i perform actions with the QTextCursor for real time formating (after each textChanged-Signal), it often crashes and I don't know, why. (Yes you don't have a crystal ball, but read on)

Are there common tasks to achieve my goal? What would be a good commonly used approach?
I would like to know how this is done in such programs but don't have the source.
Please give me some advise or point to a working example, this is so driving me nuts.

Comment: It sounds like the curses module is what you are looking for http://docs.python.org/2/howto/curses.html

Comment: Sorry I don't get the point of those curses. In a nutshell, what are they used for?

Comment: it is used for getting real-time input and it can also be used to set the color of the text, an example is the lynx browser it is made using the curses framework, here is the Wikipedia link it might help you more  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_%28programming_library%29